# Unable to save unicode file properly with utf-8 encoding from HTTP response

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, pickle, decoding

I have a storage web service that manage download file and upload file that wrote in Scala Play framework. In another Django web service, I am dealing with pandas and therefore I have function that parse csv with pandas then save them to pickle format.

After I uploaded the pickle file into the storage web service, I opened the file in Atom in the storage web service and the pickle file is perfectly fine (I save the pkl in local as well for comparison). Screenshot below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiEBE.jpg

However, when I tried to download it down from storage web service into my local, some weird thing happened. Some of the symbol changed. Screenshot below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/035xw.jpg

The response header that send me the file contains Content Type which is

```
'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'
```

To save the file in django python, I tried with

```
with codecs.open(filepath + localfilename, 'w','utf-8') as localfile:
    localfile.write(res.text)
```

This will cause trouble when I use the local file to parse this pickle back to dataframe.

```
df = pandas.read_pickle(localfilepath)
```

When it tries to decode it, it logs

```
UnicodeDecodeError at /dataproc/filter_column
'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in 
range(128)
```

Since I send the requests around in Postman, it provides me another message.

```
Unicode error hint

The string that could not be encoded/decoded was: �
```

Comment: It is ok I solved it